# Filtering a Web Part list using the current month viewed on a Calendar page

Tags: web-part, calendar, filter

We have an Advertising Calendar which shows when our confirmed marketing events will happen.

At the bottom of each month’s page, my boss would like a separate list web part that filters to show only upcoming, non-scheduled items for that month (from another list).

For example, when you are in January on the Advertising Calendar page, the second web part would show the info for all items in that list where a “Month” column matches “January”. If you switch to February in the calendar, then the web part would filter to show only items where the “Month” column matches “February” and so on.

My initial thought was to try using JavaScript to grab the calendar month id (id="WPQ2_nav_header") for the page and compare that against the “Month” column or something similar, but I would prefer an easier method.

Any idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: I think I've done something like this with SP's filter web parts which are connected to the calendar WP. Each month would have its own view (so not the built-in ">" for the next month). MS has documented the usage of filter web parts here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-a-Filter-Web-Part-to-a-List-View-Web-Part-on-a-classic-page-4f3f6c10-0a1b-479d-8b4d-c4f1bf49bb3f.

Comment: I'll look into this more. I already tried it, but must not have been doing something correctly because it was not accomplishing what we want. Thanks for responding!